# How to install oracle-java8-installer after the new update

Tags: java, docker, ubuntu

After the new update in the oracle java8, I am not able to install `java` on my `ubuntu` system. It shows this error

```
E: Package 'oracle-java8-installer' has no installation candidate
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: 
The command '/bin/sh -c echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | debconf-set-selections &&   add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java &&   apt-get update &&   apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer &&   rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* &&   rm -rf /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

I am trying to install it in my `Docker` system.

I have tried googling everywhere but could not find any answer anywhere. All answers are outdated.

Comment: Why don't you use `openjdk:8-jre-alpine`. It works well with Oracle JDK based applications?

Comment: Add your Dockerfile. What's the base image?

Comment: ubuntu:xenial is my base image

Answer (score 2):

After the discontinuation of `oracle JAVA(JDK)8 Install PPA`, I was facing the same issue with ubuntu:bionic base image, so I installed amazon correcto openjdk8.

Here is my working java RUN command from my dockerfile

```
RUN wget https://d3pxv6yz143wms.cloudfront.net/8.212.04.2/java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto-jdk_8.212.04-2_amd64.deb && \
    apt-get update &&  apt-get install java-common && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils && \
    dpkg --install java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto-jdk_8.212.04-2_amd64.deb
```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-8-ug/downloads-list.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-8-ug/generic-linux-install.html

Comment: I don't feel this is the right way to solve this problem

Comment: @HarshitKhetan
 The amazon correcto opendjk did work for my customised docker image.

Comment: any solution for the alpine image?

Comment: @HarshitKhetan , I referred this website to install java in alpine image it worked for me, hope this will work for you too
reference:http://wittchen.io/2017/12/27/creating-a-docker-container-with-alpine-linux-including-java-8-and-9/

Comment: This is not good for production, 8u202 is last free version to use on production, after that, 8u211, 8u212 only can be used on production with fees